# How do I scale a 2d Barcode using TCPDF and a custom page size?

Tags: php, tcpdf

In the process of converting a Java web app to PHP I've run into a problem generating a PDF label that has a QR code on the left side.  I'm using TCPDF and its write2DBarcode function seemed to make this pretty easy. But, when I created a custom page size to match the size of the label the generated QR code became rather small and I can't seem to scale it anymore. Positioning the QR works, but it always remains the same size.  Note: This is a simple single label (not a sheet of labels) that is sent to a label printer.

Here's the code that I've been working on:

```
$custom_layout = array(28.575, 88.9);

$barcode_style = array(
    'border' => 0,
    'padding' => 2,
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
    );

$pdf = new \Elibyy\TCPDF\TCPdf('L', 'mm', $custom_layout, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.thisisatest.com', 'QRCODE,L', 2, 2, 18, 18, $barcode_style, 'T'); // N L

$pdf->Output('my_tag.pdf', 'I');
```

TCPdf is new to me so my hope is that I'm missing something straightforward, but I'm at the bang-my-head-on-the-desk phase.  I appreciate any feedback you can give me!

Thanks in advance!